# Find files in multiple stacked archieves

Tags: grep, zip, archive, tar, gzip

I need to find file by name inside archieve. The problem is, this archieve is zip, contains other archieves inside and so on. Archieves type can be .jar, .zip, .tar, .gz and many other. So the question is, what can i use to perform this kind of search without fully decompressing and extracting this archieves.